# Why $L^{\infty-}$ is not in Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, soft-question

This has the reference https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/02/10/245a-notes-5-free-probability/

I understand that the space $L^{\infty}$ is Banach space but if we define a space ${L^{\infty-}:= \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty L^k(\Omega)}$ i.e space with finite moments than $L^{\infty-}$ is not Banach space. Can anyone please explain what does this exactly mean?  What is missing in $L^{\infty-}$ to be Banach space? More importantly why Gaussians are in $L^{\infty-}$ not in $L^{\infty}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Gaussian random variable is not a.s. bounded because $P(|X|>c)>0$ for all $c$ (although these tail probabilities become very small). That $L^{\infty-}$ *is not a Banach space* needs a proper interpretation because a Banach space is a *pair* $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ consisting of a real or complex vector space $X$ and a complete norm on it. Using the axiom of choice I believe one can construct indeed a complete norm on $L^{\infty-}$ (because, for reasonable probability spaces, it is a $c$-dimensional vector space and hence linearly isomorphic to any given separable Banach space) -- however, Tao probably means that there is no "natural"complete norm on $L^{\infty-}$. The natural structure of such a countable intersection of Banach spaces is that of a *Frechet space*.

Comment: What exactly a.s. means please?

Comment: @Creator I reckon "almost surely", that is almost everywhere (abbreviated "a.e.") for probability measures.

Comment: @haemi Ops Thank you.